# ES6 with React and Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify

So I am trying to use ES6's import statement with React and browserify to create a web app. I am having some hurdles and here is the first one.

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Start = React.createClass({
  getText: function() {
    return 'hi'
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1 className="jumbotron">{this.getText()}</h1>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Start />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="../build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are my node dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  }
```

Here is the command I use to try to transpile my code with watchify:

```
watchify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] index.js -o ../build/bundle.js
```

Here is the error I get:

```
/Users/httpnick/react/csgo-cache/public/js/index.js:1
import React from 'react';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I was fighting this all weekend and not sure what to do. If I remove the imports and just use `require()`s it works, but import just does not like to work for me. Any help fixing this issue or things I could check would be greatly appreciated.. I really want to get into ES6 with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `.babelrc` file in your project structure which could contain:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

As you are using CLI, you could pass in the missing `es2015` like so:

```
watchify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] index.js -o ../build/bundle.js
```

(notice the additional `es2015` in the line above, that is the only difference from your code).

Comment: He's passing `--presets` to the commend, he just left `es2015` out and only did `react`.

Comment: Hey thank you for your feedback. I tried adding a `.babelrc` file to the root of my project and get this error: `ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-react-jsx" specified in "/Users/httpnick/react/csgo-cache/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/httpnick/react/csgo-cache" while parsing file: /Users/httpnick/react/csgo-cache/public/js/index.js`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Do you know the correct watchify command I should use then? Or what dependencies I am missing?

Comment: @httpNick: take a look at the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks guys. That solved the issue! ++++ (I will accept the answer in 2 minutes as stack overflow is restricting me for the moment.)